# setState not firing in useEffect for Next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm using next.js and have the following code on the client side.

```js
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import { UserContext } from "../context";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const Nav = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState("TEST");
  const [state, setState] = useContext(UserContext);
  const router = useRouter();

  // Check first if we are running client side (vs server side)
  // If so, then set state to the pathname. Update on change
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("router.asPath ", router.asPath);
    console.log("window.location.pathname is ", window.location.pathname);
    console.log(typeof window !== "undefined");
    if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
      console.log("this ran before");
      setCurrent(router.asPath);
      console.log("this ran after");
      console.log("current is ", current);
    }
  }, [typeof window !== "undefined" && window.location.pathname]);
  //...
}
```

I get the following in the console...

```
router.asPath  /register
window.location.pathname is  /register
true
this ran before
this ran after
current is TEST
```

I can see that each console.log() is firing in useEffect and returning all the correct values. But setCurrent() doesn't appear to fire. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the code **finshes running** react will check if there was a state update and if so, **only then** the value of the useState hook is updated and this leads to a new render in which the new value is availabe so the new data is displayed in the ui.

```js
const [example,setExemple] = useState("")
//...
const newValue = "new"
setExample(newValue);
console.log(example)// output "" and this is normal
```

so if you want to see the new value of the state it's not possible from where you are logging because the component didn't rerendered yet, however since updating state leads to a new render `console.log` like this from JSX to understand better what'sgoing on:

```js
<div className="App">
  {console.log("this is a new render and this is my current : ",current)}
  //...
</div>
```

Comment: So with your console logging method above I get a console log that shows current to be blank, then I get two that have the path name. I'm getting the one with the pathname twice because of strict mode, correct?

Comment: Yeah `useEffect` runs when the component finishes rendering and run twice the first time if stric mode this `true` take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75711384/13488990) where I explained in detail

Answer (score 1):

setCurrent would be an asynchronous operation, and as a result, the original value gets output in the console.

If you want to take an action once the state update is complete, you could add another useEffect.

For example, adding this will log every time the state value updates:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(current);
}, [current]);
```

Very clear explanation here as well: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value

Comment: Thank you. Your answer technically answers my question. However, when I use "current" in the dependency array, the variable doesn't update when I click on navigation links. Guess I need another solution.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you are asking why this "setCurrent(router.asPath);" didn't fire. it does fire but react does all the set state at the end of the function together. in this case at the end of the useEffect. you can do the code David wrote to see the change